# Копирование текста в буфер обмена

Tags: python, клавиатура

У меня есть здача: получить содержимое буфера обмена. Делаю с помощью `pyperclip`.

Я получаю содержимое буфера обмена с помощью комбинаций клавиш (`keyboard`) так:

```
def take():
    import pyperclip
    return pyperclip.paste()

import keyboard
keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + C', lambda: take())
```

Когда я начинаю копировать с Ctrl + C на Windows, то у меня копируется предыдущее значение, хранящееся в буфере обмена.

Если я хочу скопировать *test1*, а затем *test2*, то у меня два раза выводится *test1*.

Comment: Откуда вы пытаетесь скопировать текст?

Comment: Например блокнот

Comment: А причем тут блокнот? Буфер обмена относится к операционной системе а не к приложению в нем, а кто сказал что все приложения работают с буфером и все сочетания клавиш перехватывают?

Comment: Тем более кто сказал что ваш код выполняется в нужный момент?

Comment: Была идея сделать из этого службу и перехватывать новое значение из буфера обмена в этот скрипт

Comment: А зачем тут вообще питон?

Comment: Не знаю, захотелось сделать не питоне

Answer (score 1):

Решил с помощью перезагрузки модуля `pyperclip`

```
from importlib import reload
import pyperclip
def take():
    reload(pyperclip)
    return pyperclip.paste()

import keyboard
keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + C', lambda: take())
```